# Is it possible to scope/group event publishers in NServiceBus?

Tags: nservicebus, azure-table-storage, publisher, subscriber, azure-storage-queues

I have:
- one subscriber SUB with QUEUE0
- publisher PUB1 with QUEUE1
- publisher PUB2 with QUEUE2
- event `MyEvent` being published by both publishers

When:
- SUB explicitly subscribes to PUB1 with queue name QUEUE1 only

```
subscriberEndpointConfiguration.UnicastRouting().AddPublisher("PUB1", typeof(MyEvent));
```

Outcome:
- SUB also receives `MyEvent` from PUB2 (which has queue name QUEUE2)

Expected:
- SUB should not receive `MyEvent` from PUB2, because it's not subscribed to that publisher queue name

From NSB wiki:

> subscribers express interest in one or more classes, and only receive messages that are of interest, without knowledge of what, if any, publishers there are

**Questions**:

1. What's the point of specifying the publisher endpoint in the `AddPublisher` method shown above? The Subscription table in the Azure Table Storage has an event type and a subscriber columns only, publisher endpoint is not stored.
2. If `AddPublisher` is some sort of an obsolete method, then the `endpointInstance.Subscribe<MyEvent>()` simply fails - it says "no publishers could be found".
3. Is it possible to scope/group publishers so having only one event type `MyEvent` the subscribers will receive that events from publishers which are created with the same queue name only?
   E.g. you create PUB1 with QUEUE-A, PUB2 with queue QUEUE-A, PUB3 with QUEUE-B, and SUB with `AddPublisher` to QUEUE-A, so the SUB does not receive `MyEvent` from PUB3 (QUEUE-B).

I'm using:
NServiceBus 6.0.0-beta0004
NServiceBus.Persistence.AzureStorage 1.0.0-beta0004
NServiceBus.Azure.Transports.WindowsAzureStorageQueues 7.0.0-beta0004

Comment: Are both Pub1 and Pub2 using the same `IEndpointInstance`?  (basically in the same host).  And are they using the same Persistance Configuration : `busConfiguration.UsePersistence<AzureStoragePersistence, StorageType.Subscriptions>().TableName("tableName")`?  I think each Publisher will not only need it's own Queue (to receive in coming subscription messages), but its own Persistence table to store the subscriptions.  I don't think Publishers can share a table without bleed over.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Azure Storage Queues transport supports [pub/sub using persistence](http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/messaging/publish-subscribe/#mechanics-persistence-based-subscribe). The need to specify the publisher endpoint is there to allow sending a subscription message by the subscriber upon startup. By default, all endpoints use the same shared storage table and that's why you experience what you describe. If you'd split subscriptions per endpoint (each endpoint to have its own storage table), you'd see that SUB would only receive an event from PUB1 if that's the only publisher it's subscribed to.
2. `AddPublisher()` is not an obsolete method. Obsoleted message would be marked as such. Saying that, the routing feature still can be modified during the beta stage we're in right now.
3. Scoping can be done the way Philip outlined. At the same time, I would encourage to look into why you have two different endpoints generating the same event. Usually, you'd want to have an event be unique and raised by a single endpoint (or, all of it instances), but not two or more different endpoints.

Comment: We have a scenario where we have a common service implementation, where each instance has it's own group of interested subscribers. Moreover, we'd like to tag events so only particular subscribers can receive the event.

Answer (score 1):

Each Publisher needs its own Persistence Table, in addition to its own queue.

When you setup each publisher's `IEndpointInstance`:

```
busConfiguration
   .UsePersistence<AzureStoragePersistence, StorageType.Subscriptions>()
   .TableName("NameOfPublisher")
```

See the documentation for more info: http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/azure-storage-persistence/configuration